# Summarize observations of the same country and year in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that identifies observations based on two variables: Time and Country. The variable of interest is dichotomous, and has the value 0 if the event didn't occur and 1 if it did.
For some countries more than one observation is reported per year.
The data can be summarized like this:

| Country | Time | Conflict | Bio Weapons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 2000 | 2 | 0 |
| B | 2000 | 3 | 1 |
| C | 2000 | 4 | 0 |
| D | 2000 | 5 | 1 |
| D | 2000 | 6 | 0 |
| D | 2000 | 7 | 0 |
| D | 2000 | 8 | 1 |

Is it possible two colapse these multiple observations into one observation per year and country with either outcome 0 (if the event never occured) or 1(if the event occured at least once)? Like this?:

| Country | Time | Bio Weapons |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000 | 0 |
| B | 2000 | 1 |
| C | 2000 | 0 |
| D | 2000 | 1 |

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please provide the input data in reproducible form using `dput` and the expected output.  See the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  Also any code attempts would be useful.

Comment: What happened to country B in your example output?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is a bit unlcear since it doesn't match with what your description is, but this is what I think you want:

```
dat %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(Country, Time) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(Bio_Weapons = dplyr::if_else(1 %in% Bio.Weapons, 1,  0))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Country [4]
  Country  Time Bio_Weapons
  <chr>   <int>       <dbl>
1 A        2000           0
2 B        2000           1
3 C        2000           0
4 D        2000           1
```

And since I like `data.table` solutions:

```
dat[, .(Bio_Weapons = fifelse(1 %in% Bio.Weapons, 1, 0)), by=c("Country", "Time")]
```

```
   Country Time Bio_Weapons
1:       A 2000           0
2:       B 2000           1
3:       C 2000           0
4:       D 2000           1
```

Answer (score 0):

An option without `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(Country, Time) %%
    summarise(Bio_Weapons = +(1 %in% Bio.Weapons))
```